# Possible to add shortcut names to razor namespace imports in MVC 3 web.config

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-3

Similar to `using Shortcut = System.Whatever;` in the cshtml I have so far been out of luck doing something similar in the webconfig

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" as="Routing" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Something like that...Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible in Razor because there is no mechanism in C# that would allow you to redefine a namespace.

Comment: Well, the reason I bring it up is because you can define an alternate name in c#. `using shortname = System.Text` is one example but that's on a per file basis.

Comment: @Morder technically it's on a per-type basis :) In general you should think of Razor as an extension of C# (or VB); there are few additional concepts that it adds to the existing languages.

Comment: Yeah, I just hoped... :) Would be nice to have though. I've made it an HtmlHelper instead so that it's still a short type. Thanks.